# hcidump not acquiring data packets in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to communicate between two bluetooth modules in two different Ubuntu 14.04 VMs.

While the data is transmitted and received perfectly, the hcidump is not able to acquire that data. I also tried Wireshark, but it is also not displaying the data packets. However, both hcidump and wireshark are able to sniff the event information.

For hcidump, I am using the following command:

```
hcidump -t -R -i hci1
```

Here is the snapshot of the wireshark screen :

[image]

So, if anyone here has faced similar problem before or know how to get Hcidump/Wireshark to sniff data packets then please care to wager in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I will answer my own question, in case someone face the same problem in future.

I found that I was using Hcidump without sudo option. Hence, I was only able to log the events and not the data packets.
Using it with sudo worked out perfectly fine.